# how can solve this error pro_widgets elementor api.php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Notice: Undefined index: pro_widgets in /var/www/html/wp_themes/latest/qreate_marketing/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php on line 160

how can I resolve this error

Comment: Hello, this is not an _error_, but a _notice_. You could search or a way to disable php notices in your environment.

Comment: This is not a proper way to remove a notice any another way to remove this notice?

Comment: The notice pops at line 160 : https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/includes/api.php. Open an issue on Elementor's github ?